# (C++) How can I use getline() with an integer while reading a file?

Tags: c++, file, integer, getline

I'm trying to create some code to open a file, read the content and check if a couple of integers are equal by using getline(). The problem is that it seems to work only with strings, instead of doing it with integers aswell. Could you help me?

```
fstream ficheroEntrada;
string frase;
int dni, dnitxt;
int i=0;
int time;

cout << "Introduce tu DNI: ";
cin >> dni;

ficheroEntrada.open ("Datos.txt",ios::in);
if (ficheroEntrada.is_open()) {
    while (! ficheroEntrada.eof() ) {
        getline (ficheroEntrada, dnitxt);
        if (dnitxt == dni){
            getline (ficheroEntrada, frase);
            cout << dni << " " << frase << endl;        
        }else{
            getline (ficheroEntrada, dnitxt);
        }   
    }
    ficheroEntrada.close();
}
```

Comment: Use `ficheroEntrada >> dnitxt;` instead.

Comment: did any of the answers help with your problem ? care to give more feedback ?

Answer (score 2):

getline() member function is used to extract string input. So it would be better if you input data in form of string and then use "stoi" (stands for string to integer) to extract only integer values from the string data.
You can check how to use "stoi" seperately.

Answer (score 1):

[`getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) doesn't read an integer, only a string, a whole line at a time.

If I understand correctly, you are searching for the `int dni` into the file `Datos.txt`. What is the format of the file ?

Assuming it looks something like this:

```
4
the phrase coressponding to 4
15
the phrase coressponding to 15
...
```

You can use [`stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) to convert what you've read into an integer:

```
string dni_buffer;
int found_dni
if (ficheroEntrada.is_open()) {
    while (! ficheroEntrada.eof() ) {
        getline (ficheroEntrada, dni_buffer);
        found_dni = stoi(dni_buffer);
        if (found == dni){
            getline (ficheroEntrada, frase);
            cout << dni << " " << frase << endl;        
        }else{
            // discard the text line with the wrong dni
            // we can use frase as it will be overwritten anyways
            getline (ficheroEntrada, frase);
        }   
    }
    ficheroEntrada.close();
}
```

This is not tested.

Answer (score 1):

**C++** has two type of `getline`.
One of them is a non-member function in `std::string`. This version **extracts** from a stream into a `std::string object` [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Like:

```
std::string line;
std::getline( input_stream, line );
```

The other one is a member function of an **input-stream** like `std::ifstream` and this version **extracts** from the stream into an **array of character** [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) like:

```
char array[ 50 ];
input_stream( array, 50 );
```

---

**NOTE**
Both versions **extracts** characters from a stream **NOT** a real integer type!

---

For having an answer to your question, you should know what type of data you have in your file. A file like this: `I have only 3 $dollars!`; when you try to read that, by using `std::getline` or `input_stream.getline` you **cannot**  extract `3` as in integer type!. Instead of `getline` you can use `operator >>` to extract a single data one-by-one; like:
`input_stream >> word_1 >> word_2 >> word_3 >> int_1 >> word_4;`.

Now `int_1` has the value: `3`

---

**Practical Example**

```
std::ifstream input_stream( "file", std::ifstream::in );
int number_1;
int number_2;
while( input_stream >> number_1 >> number_2 ){
    std::cout << number_1 << " == " << number_2 << " : " << ( number_1 == number_2 ) << '\n';
}
input_stream.close();
```

The output:

```
10 == 11 : 0
11 == 11 : 1
12 == 11 : 0
```